# How to continuously output screenshots while also outputting hls with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

So I have the following process of ingesting rtsp and output hls.

```
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer \
 -rtsp_transport udp \
 -i rtsp://<source>/ \
 -vsync 0 \
 -copyts \
 -vcodec copy \
 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
 -an \
 -hls_flags delete_segments \
 -f segment \
 -segment_list_flags live \
 -segment_time 1 \
 -segment_list_size 5 \
 -segment_format mpegts \
 -segment_list streaming.m3u8 \
 -segment_list_type m3u8 \
 -segment_list_entry_prefix ./ \
  %d.ts
```

and I want to also output screenshots from the stream at some fixed frequency. Say every second.
I've tried a variety of options including

```
-vframes 1 -q:v 10 capture.jpeg
```

and its not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer \
 -rtsp_transport udp \
 -i rtsp://<source>/ \
 -vsync 0 \
 -copyts \
 -vcodec copy \
 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
 -an \
 -hls_flags delete_segments \
 -f segment \
 -segment_list_flags live \
 -segment_time 1 \
 -segment_list_size 5 \
 -segment_format mpegts \
 -segment_list streaming.m3u8 \
 -segment_list_type m3u8 \
 -segment_list_entry_prefix ./ \
  %d.ts \
 -q:v 10 -vf fps=1 output_%03d.jpg
```